# Wine 2.21 Staging - Epic Games Launcher - dotnet40 in 64bit prefix

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux, winetricks

(WineHQ Epic Games Launcher page ->  https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35811  )

While trying to install Epic Games Launcher with wine (64bit Prefix), the Prerequisites always fail to install. The WineHQ page for Epic Games Launcher states that the workaround for this is: "Winetricks from current git can be used to install dotnet40 in a 64-bit prefix."

I have run the command `WINEREFIX=$HOME/.wine64 winetricks dotnet40`,  which returns a few errors* before trying to install .NET 4.0, and stating

> "Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer."

What exactly is needed to finish the installation?

*Errors:

Actual Launcher Error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s01ks.jpg

```
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
```

.

```
This package may not fully work on a 64-bit installation. 32-bit prefixes may work better.
```

.

```
dotnet40 does not yet fully work or install on wine.  Caveat emptor.
```

.

```
Mono does not appear to be installed.
```